# Visual Studio 2008 Keyboard Shortcut to display Members?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the best way to display the Members in the current file in VS2008?

**SCENARIO**:
You open a file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and then type “>of ” and SomeFilename, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you end up in the newly opened  file. Now if you don’t remember a method’s name or a member’s name, you might try to incrementally search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and/or various search options, but what I want to know is how can I see/open/scroll-through/etc the Member combo box (or similar alternative).

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I know about the Navigation Bar (it is “on” by default for c#), and that’s exactly what I want to do, go there *without using the mouse*. There’s a keyboard shortcut: `Window.MovetoNavigationBar` which is so far the only option i’ve found. But you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move from types to Members.

Comment: @Martin: See the modified answer by me below. Ctrl + F2 is the option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew is right.

Alternatively, there is Object Browser. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>J</kbd>

EDIT: The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
And, you will have to hold it together for little more than a second to reach the dropdown.

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to drop the combobox.
While you are in the "Types" dropdown, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the "Members" dropdown.

Comment: Object browser is very ineffective, I’m already in the file, i want to find a method or member contrary to browsing the entire .NET (which would work, but it’s not what I’m looking for.

Comment: yes, the behavior is weird. I guess that it’s either reshaper or cumberstone VS option. :S Thanks.

Comment: thank you for the Alt + Down to drop the combobox list; I wish I knew that 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Use the navigation bar at the top of the IDE - the one on the right hand side lists all members of the current type.

If you don't see the navigation bar then you can enable it this way:

> `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Navigation Bar`

Comment: I have the navigation bar, that’s the two combo boxes, Types on the left, Members on the right. I want to know how to go there **without** using the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Buy ReSharper and use its [File Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#File_Structure) window. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For navigation I recommend using [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) . It provides quick navigation to members in code editor, as well navigation to files and class declarations.

Of course ReSharper provides these featuresand much more, but DPack is free and quite lightweight.

http://www.usysware.com/dpack/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to see is to map the Window.MovetoNavigationBar, you still have to press tab to pass from Types to Members, and down arrow key to see the list, there’s no incremental search (only the first char). I was hoping there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Ctrl + F2 seems to be the shortcut. But it is not working consistently.